# q kdb - w64 gives 'host exception on startup

Tags: kdb

I have a licensed 64-bit q version on my windows machine, have set QHOME to the directory that contains `w64` and `k4.lic` and appended `path/to/w64/` to `PATH`.

When I start q I get
`'host` error.

Before I was using 32-bit q (directly downloaded from kx systems) and it worked fine.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

sorry the reason was that I was using the wrong license file